# jquery, identify this id within this section?

Tags: jquery

I want to identify the full id tag, not sure how to do it:

```
    \$("div[id^='reportdate-'] input[name='radiovalue']").change(function(event) {

        var id_value = \$(this).attr('id');

        var value= \$("div[id^='reportdate-'] input[name='radiovalue']:checked").val();

        alert(value);

        alert(id_value); // NOT WORKING!!

    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the id of the radiobutton or the div?

Comment: What do you want the id of? the div or the input?

Comment: the \ is because this is implemented within perl, want the id of the div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to get the ID of the input. You probably should use:

```
$(this).parent().attr("id");
```

If the input isn't a direct child of the id you want. You can use:

```
$(this).closest("[id^='reportdate-']").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want the parent div's id and not the inputs id. You can use `.parent()`

```
$(this).parent().attr('id');
```